# I need to figure out the last time that a function was used by SQL Server. How can I do this?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, functions

I work with databases that contain thousands of stored procedures and hundreds of functions.  I have found on-line methods to track the usage of stored procedures; however, I haven't seen the same for functions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Change Data Capture or Change tracking to analyse the required changes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb933994(v=sql.110).aspx)

You might need to drill down more with Sql server audit to capture the required use for the function in question [SQL Server Audit Action Groups and Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280663(v=sql.110).aspx)

Also,

You can get a possible idea as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765322/how-do-i-find-out-how-often-a-udf-sp-has-been-called-since-creation-or-last-wee):using below query

```
SELECT usecounts
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE sys.dm_exec_sql_text.objectid=object_id('YourFunction')
```

So basically you have to find a proper way to analyse the usage.

Comment: Thanks KASQLDBA. I was hoping to find something with a small footprint like the following for stored procedure usage: SELECT OB.name, OB.object_id AS [ObjectID], MAX(last_execution_time) AS [LastRun] FROM sys.objects AS [OB] INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS [DMEPS] ON OB.object_id = DMEPS.object_id WHERE OB.type = 'P' AND DMEPS.database_id = DB_ID() GROUP BY OB.name, OB.object_id;  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Your usecounts query gets me part of the way there.